# ImportError Django (but I think its because of python)

Tags: python, django, version, importerror

I working in a project that uses python 3.6.9 and django 3.1.1 using it on a virtual enviroment with virtualenv, somerall python in my computer updated to the version 3.8.2 (I think it's because i updated ubuntu to 20.04 version) and somerall changed the virtual enviroment too , and now i can't even run the server.
this is the steps that i do:

```
source bin/activate
```

in the folder of my project i do that:

```
python manage.py runserver
```

but It keeps given this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 11, in main
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 13, in main
    raise ImportError(
ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?
```

if I enter this comand on virtual environment:

```
$ python3 --version
//gives:
Python 3.8.2
```

to solve this i tried some think's like:

1. installing python 3.6.9 with requirements.txt

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

but it didn't localizate the command pip

2. soo i tried with pip3

```
pip3 install -r requirements.txt
```

but it didn't work again..

if I miss some information about the problem please tell me...
I new here!

Comment: Is Django installed ? Do you have a module named Django ?

Comment: Please, show you project tree

Comment: Try remove your virtual environment folder and create in again with `pyhton3 -m venv venv`, then `source venv/bin/activate` and check if you have `(venv)` prefix at your console line.

Comment: Actually i don't know... it not show me the version of django

Comment: It work !!!!! thank you